# Default value in 'gsub'

Tags: arrays, ruby, gsub

I have an array that looks like this:

```
arr = [
  "---\n",
  ":date: 2018-07-31\n  :story_points: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-01\n  :story_points:    \n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-22\n  :story_points: 8.0\n  :remaining_hours: 0.0\n "
]
```

I want to extract the values for `date` and `story_points` in respective arrays. If the value for `story_points` is missing, then the default value of `"0.0"` should be given. The output should look like below:

```
["2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22"]
["4.0", "0.0", "8.0"]
```

I have tried the following as suggested in my earlier post by another user:

```
arr.join.gsub(/(?<=:date: )\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/).to_a
arr.join.gsub(/(?<=:story_points: )\d{1}.\d{1}/).to_a
```

The above will give:

```
["2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22"]
["4.0", "8.0"]
```

I cannot fetch the default values. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What format is that? Some kind of YAML?

Comment: You have to escape `.` in the second regex if that is intended to match a decimal point.

Comment: The array is a result from the database. I have a Text column in MySql database which stores all these information in a single column

Comment: @sawa: Could you please elaborate a bit. Escaping of . did not work for me

Comment: @vishwastej This is very likely serialized data as e.g. used by Rails. You can (and should) use `YAML.load` to parse this data into a Hash instead of trying to extract the data with regular expressions.

Comment: I am not claiming that escaping the `.` will solve your problem. I am claiming that that is an additional problem with your code, besides your issue.

Comment: @sawa Understood your point.

Comment: I edited merely to set a local variable (`arr`) equal to the array in your example. That way, readers can simply refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it. (All answers fortuitously used `arr` for that array.) That should be done for all objects in examples (here just the one).  You may wish to replace "respective arrays" (there is just one!) with "this array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following code:

```
arr[1..-1].map { |s| (s.match(/(?<=:story_points: )\d{1}.\d{1}/) || '0.0').to_s }
#=> ["4.0", "0.0", "8.0"]
```

Comment: You could simplify to `arr[1..-1].map { |s| s[/(?<=:story_points: )\d.\d/] || '0.0' }`, in part because `\d{1}` is the same as `\d` and `to_s` has no effect. This assumes that there is only one line `"---\n"` and that it appears at the beginning, that `2.37` can be extracted as `2.3` and that `12.3` is not permitted.  Moreover, this requires the date strings to be extracted as a separate operation (as the OP has done), which may not be the best approach.

Comment: Thank you @CarySwoveland, this may not be the best approach but since the OP question is how to put default value `0.0` when the value for `story_points` is missing so I'm assuming that the Regex part is already correct.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative regex based solution based on a single pass over the array:

```
arr = [
  "---\n",
  ":date: 2018-07-31\n  :story_points: 4.0\n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-01\n  :story_points:    \n  :remaining_hours: 4.0\n ",
  ":date: 2018-08-22\n  :story_points: 8.0\n  :remaining_hours: 0.0\n "
]
dates = []
sp = []
rx = /:date:\s*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s*:story_points:\s*(\d+\.\d+)?/
arr.each { |x| x.scan(rx) { |m,n| dates << m; sp << (n || "0.0")  } }
# => dates: [ "2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22" ]
# => sp: [ "4.0", "0.0", "8.0" ]
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/1dgNp9)

Here is the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/9oO66sP9D4)

**Pattern explanation**

- `:date:` - a literal `:date:` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` - Capturing group 1: a date-like pattern
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `:story_points:` - a literal `:story_points:` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+\.\d+)?` - Capturing group 2 (optional, due to `?`): 1+ digits, `.` and 1+ digits.

Comment: Thank  you Wiktor for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = /
    \A                  # match beginning of string
    :date:              # match string
    [ ]+                # match one or more spaces
    (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) # match string in capture group 1
    \n                  # match newline
    [ ]+                # match one or more spaces
    :story_points:      # match string
    [ ]+                # match one or more paces
    (                   # begin capture group 2
      \d+\.\d+          # match a non-negative float 
      |                 # or
      [ ]+              # match one or more spaces
    )                   # end capture group 2
    /x                  # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
arr.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  res = s.scan(r).flatten
  a << res unless res.empty?
end.transpose.tap { |a| a[1].map! { |s| s.to_f.to_s } }
  #=> [["2018-07-31", "2018-08-01", "2018-08-22"], ["4.0", "0.0", "8.0"]]
```

In conventional form the regular expression is as follows.

```
    r = /\A:date: +(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\n +:story_points: +(\d+\.\d+| +)/
```

Spaces outside character classes are removed when free-spacing mode is used, which is why I've replaced `[ ]` with spaces in the conventional form of the regex. `/ +\n/` can be replaced by `/\s+/` but that permits tabs, other whitespace characters, no spaces and multiple newlines, which may not be desired.

Note the following intermediate calculation.

```
arr.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  res = s.scan(r).flatten
  a << res unless res.empty?
end
  #=> [["2018-07-31", "4.0"], ["2018-08-01", " "], ["2018-08-22", "8.0"]]
```

I've used [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) in place of the following.

```
a = arr.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  res = s.scan(r).flatten
  a << res unless res.empty?
end.transpose
a[1].map! { |s| s.to_f.to_s }
a
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Cary.